Creating a large Zip from files present in Blob storage in Dotnet core
We are trying to create a zip of all the files related to a particular environment (which would be 100s of 1000s in number with average size of 100KB). After zipping the size of zip file would be around 40-50GB normally and more than that in case of exceptions. These files are stored in Azure blob storage.
We are creating an endpoint to achieve this so that the task can run in background since it will take time to complete.
The hosted service will only have maximum of 2GB of RAM and same memory will be used for file system as well.
I tried creating the endpoint which perform the following flow:

Gets the number of related files in Blob.
Iterate through the all the files 1 by 1.
Gets the file from blob.
Add or append the downloaded file in a zip (saved in temp folder).
Add metadata in a CSV file.
Upload the zip and CSV file in a public Blob.
Delete the files from the temp folder.

How we can achieve this task, can we do it with streaming?
I have a doubt in streaming process that if we create a zip file in Azure blob and append the files dynamically, Will it be able to create a file bigger than 2GB?
I think while appending the service will download the zip file in-memory and then again uploads it in cloud, so creating a file bigger than 2GB is impossible. Let me know, if I assuming it wrong.
Regards

Technically should be possible. With ZipArchive your stream does not have to be seekable, so old data does not necessary have to be loaded in memory. You could create your own Stream. E.g. one that creates the zip stream and loads in new files into an underlying memory stream as additional data is requested. Maybe there's already a (better) implementation created by somebody.

Thanks @NotFound for confirming that it is possible. I'll try and find some solution if posted.

There's apparently a method in the sdk to retrieve a Stream to write to, which will make it way easier to directly write to the storage as output.

The BlockBlobClient has a method OpenWriteAsync which returns a Stream. You can directly insert that as output stream into the ZipArchive constructor and copy your file data to it. The resulting Stream will write the data to the storage while only requiring to buffer one file at a time in memory.
